# How to retrieve from an array of objects and generate VictoryPie - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach

In the below code snippet I can see the jobs array in my console which consist of array of Project objects. Each Project has jobName and numberOfHighPriorityWarnings. (Please look at the code you will understand how I'm setting these objects to the array).

I want to display these in VictoryPie [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHF6P.png). Each Project objects jobName should set to x and numberOfHighPriorityWarnings should set to y variable in the VictoryPie. I assume here I should create a ForEach loop that iterates through this.state.jobs and retrieve it's jobName and numberOfHighPriorityWarnings then create VictoryPie data dynamically. But I'm new to React so appreciate if you could show me how to do it. Thanks in advance!

```
render() {

    console.log(this.state.jobs);


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Results</h1>
        </header>

        <VictoryPie 
          data={[
            { x: "job name here", y: numberOfHighPriorityWarning },
            { x: "job name here", y: numberOfHighPriorityWarning }
          ]}
        />    

      </div>
    );
  }
```

FYI this is how I'm setting data to results array:

```
this.state.jobs.push(new Project(job, status, numberOfHighPriorityWarnings, numberOfNormalPriorityWarnings, numberOfLowPriorityWarnings));
```

This is how console.log(this.state.jobs) looks like,

[image: console.log(this.state.jobs)]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHF6P.png) https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie/

Comment: If your this.state.results looks like what you have passed as data. Then you just need to pass it like this data={this.state.results}. If this is not what you need , give structure of results , post a complete code

Comment: Please check the question I have edited and put exact information, console output etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading on official documentation I found out if we set data to state directly it does not trigger a render function. Also It could result in various lifecycle problems. Then, as the Documentation mentioned I followed below approach with Hammad Akhwand's render approach and got this working.

```
var jobs = this.state.jobs.slice()
jobs.push(new Project(job, status, numberOfHighPriorityWarnings, numberOfNormalPriorityWarnings, numberOfLowPriorityWarnings))
this.setState({ jobs: jobs })
```

Answer (score 0):

When transforming an array to a different array, `map` function is very useful. In your case, you could use it like this:

```
<VictoryPie data={this.state.jobs.map(function (job) {
    return {
      x : job.jobName,
      y : job.numberOfHighPriorityWarnings
    };
})} />
```

Comment: I tried this still VictoryPie is not visible in the browser.. It works for mock data but not for the data iterate through the array.